# Angular - Change css using ng-style

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-style

I am trying to change top position of a DIV on Scroll event -

In controller i have-

```
    angular.element($window).on("scroll", function(e) {
        vm.scrollTop = angular.element($window).scrollTop()+'px';
        console.log(vm.scrollTop);
    });
```

In html -

```
<div ng-style="{'top': vm.scrollTop}">
    Hello World
</div>
```

On scroll event is printing scrollTop values in console but "Div" style never gets updated.

Please correct me if this is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: `ng-style` take an `expression` not a `value`, try this `<div ng-style="{'top': vm.scrollTop}">`

Comment: I updated my question for the same but run time expression are not updating style of the div (top -> calculated scroll)

Comment: Close your attribute with a double quote.

Comment: You also need to call `$scope.$apply();` after setting `vm.scrollTop` because the event handler is executing outside of angular's awareness.

Comment: Well, $scope.$apply does that. Thanks Jim. 
You mind providing above comment as answer, i will mark it as the answer for others

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `$scope.$apply();` after setting `vm.scrollTop` because the event handler is executing outside of angular's awareness.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$scope.$apply` or `$scope.$watch`.

Here's snippet using `$scope.$apply`.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope, $document, $window) {
   $scope.scrollTop = 30;
     $document.bind('scroll', function(){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
   $scope.scrollTop = $window.scrollY;
      });
   });
   $scope.getStyle = function(){
        var styles = {}
        styles['margin-top'] = $scope.scrollTop + 'px';
        return styles;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Top</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
     <div ng-style="getStyle()">
         Hello World
     </div>
  </div>
 <div style="height: 1000px; border: solid 2px red;"></div>
</div>
```